# what is the best way to access calendar of microsoft exchange server 2016 from 3rd party client application?

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-calendar, exchange-server-2016

We are trying to build a node js based client application to access calendar of microsoft on-premises exchange server 2016. We studied about outlook calendar api and Exchange Web Services(EWS). As I know, outlook calendar api is not allowed to access on-premises exchange server.
I want to know

1. Is there any way to use outlook calendar api to access calendar or
   have to use EWS?

If we have to use EWS

1. Is there any good node js module for EWS ?
2. Does EWS provide all functionalities of calendar (such as outlook
   calendar api provides all capability of calendar)?

Answer (score 1):

you can not use outlook calendar api (Office 365 specific) to access on premises Exchange Servers, these are Office 365 only.

You can actually use ews with nodejs, take a look at [ews-javascript-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ews-javascript-api) module. This is complete port of c# counterpart.

EWS does provide all of the features you can do in Outlook, in fact Outlook for MAC is based on EWS only.

if you can be specific to what exactly you are trying to do, I can provide sample code. You can look at [official EWS managed API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj536567(v=exchg.150).aspx) for code examples. most codes are valid except that you have to use promise style, see github readme and issues for more code samples.